# scrolling touch position to the center of the view in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have label with text inside UIScrollView. When touch event occurred, i want to scroll my label with text so the text underneath the touch point will scroll to the center of the view. If i have touch event coordinates, how i can scroll UIScrollView's content from touch point to the center of the screen? Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[myScroll setContentOffset: CGPointMake(x, y) animated: YES];
```

Where x,y is the top-left corner position of myScroll where you have to scroll, calculated from the touch event coordinates.